# MSVC error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol

Tags: c, windows, visual-studio, visual-c++

I am trying to compile a Python library containing cython bindings into the FFTW library, which is written in C. I am on a Windows machine and have updated to the latest MSVC build tools. I have both Build Tools 2017 (v15.9.22) and Build Tools 2019 (v16.5.4) installed.

I created a separate conda environment named `tsne` using `conda create --name tsne python=3.7.4` and installed FFTW using conda using `conda install -c conda-forge fftw`. My `setup.py` defines the appropriate extensions and directories to compile the modules. For instance, the include dirs for C headers are properly included in `miniconda3\envs\tsne\Library\include`, as well as the library directories with `miniconda3\envs\tsne\Library\lib`.

When I attempt to compile the extension which relies on FFTW, I get the following error

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.25.28610\bin\HostX86\x64\cl.exe
  /c /nologo /Ox /W3 /GL /DNDEBUG /MD -IC:\Users\pavli\miniconda3\envs\tsne\include
  -IC:\Users\pavli\miniconda3\envs\tsne\Library\include
  -IC:\Users\pavli\miniconda3\envs\tsne\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\include
  -IC:\Users\pavli\miniconda3\envs\tsne\include
  -IC:\Users\pavli\miniconda3\envs\tsne\include
  "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.25.28610\include"
  "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\ucrt"
  "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\shared"
  "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\um"
  "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\winrt"
  "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\cppwinrt"
  /TcopenTSNE/_matrix_mul/matrix_mul_fftw3.c
  /Fobuild\temp.win-amd64-3.7\Release\openTSNE/_matrix_mul/matrix_mul_fftw3.obj  
  /Ox  /openmp
  matrix_mul_fftw3.c

C:\Users\pavli\miniconda3\envs\tsne\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\include\numpy\npy_1_7_deprecated_api.h(14) : Warning Msg: Using deprecated NumPy API, disable it with #define NPY_NO_DEPRECATED_API NPY_1_7_API_VERSION
openTSNE/_matrix_mul/matrix_mul_fftw3.c(2704): warning C4244: 'function': conversion from 'Py_ssize_t' to 'int', possible loss of data
openTSNE/_matrix_mul/matrix_mul_fftw3.c(2741): warning C4244: 'function': conversion from 'Py_ssize_t' to 'int', possible loss of data
openTSNE/_matrix_mul/matrix_mul_fftw3.c(2760): warning C4244: 'function': conversion from 'Py_ssize_t' to 'int', possible loss of data
openTSNE/_matrix_mul/matrix_mul_fftw3.c(3199): warning C4244: 'function': conversion from 'Py_ssize_t' to 'int', possible loss of data
openTSNE/_matrix_mul/matrix_mul_fftw3.c(3199): warning C4244: 'function': conversion from 'Py_ssize_t' to 'int', possible loss of data
openTSNE/_matrix_mul/matrix_mul_fftw3.c(3237): warning C4244: 'function': conversion from 'Py_ssize_t' to 'int', possible loss of data
openTSNE/_matrix_mul/matrix_mul_fftw3.c(3237): warning C4244: 'function': conversion from 'Py_ssize_t' to 'int', possible loss of data
openTSNE/_matrix_mul/matrix_mul_fftw3.c(3257): warning C4244: 'function': conversion from 'Py_ssize_t' to 'int', possible loss of data
openTSNE/_matrix_mul/matrix_mul_fftw3.c(3257): warning C4244: 'function': conversion from 'Py_ssize_t' to 'int', possible loss of data

C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.25.28610\bin\HostX86\x64\link.exe
  /nologo /INCREMENTAL:NO /LTCG /DLL /MANIFEST:EMBED,ID=2 /MANIFESTUAC:NO 
  /LIBPATH:C:\Users\pavli\miniconda3\envs\tsne\lib 
  /LIBPATH:C:\Users\pavli\miniconda3\envs\tsne\Library\lib 
  /LIBPATH:C:\Users\pavli\miniconda3\envs\tsne\libs 
  /LIBPATH:C:\Users\pavli\miniconda3\envs\tsne\PCbuild\amd64
  "/LIBPATH:C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.25.28610\lib\x64"
  "/LIBPATH:C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\lib\10.0.18362.0\ucrt\x64" 
  "/LIBPATH:C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\lib\10.0.18362.0\um\x64" 
  /EXPORT:PyInit_matrix_mul build\temp.win-amd64-3.7\Release\openTSNE/_matrix_mul/matrix_mul_fftw3.obj 
  /OUT:C:\Users\pavli\Desktop\openTSNE\openTSNE\_matrix_mul\matrix_mul.cp37-win_amd64.pyd 
  /IMPLIB:build\temp.win-amd64-3.7\Release\openTSNE/_matrix_mul\matrix_mul.cp37-win_amd64.lib 
  /Ox  /openmp

LINK : warning LNK4044: unrecognized option '/Ox'; ignored
LINK : warning LNK4044: unrecognized option '/openmp'; ignored
   Creating library build\temp.win-amd64-3.7\Release\openTSNE/_matrix_mul\matrix_mul.cp37-win_amd64.lib and object build\temp.win-amd64-3.7\Release\openTSNE/_matrix_mul\matrix_mul.cp37-win_amd64.exp
matrix_mul_fftw3.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol fftw_destroy_plan
matrix_mul_fftw3.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol fftw_plan_dft_r2c_1d
matrix_mul_fftw3.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol fftw_execute
matrix_mul_fftw3.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol fftw_plan_dft_c2r_2d
matrix_mul_fftw3.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol fftw_plan_dft_r2c_2d
matrix_mul_fftw3.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol fftw_plan_dft_c2r_1d
C:\Users\pavli\Desktop\openTSNE\openTSNE\_matrix_mul\matrix_mul.cp37-win_amd64.pyd : fatal error LNK1120: 6 unresolved externals
error: command 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio\\2019\\BuildTools\\VC\\Tools\\MSVC\\14.25.28610\\bin\\HostX86\\x64\\link.exe' failed with exit status 1120
```

The error indicates that the compiled library is not found (I guess? I'm not that familiar...). However, I can verify that the library is there. So `miniconda3\envs\tsne\Library\lib\fftw3.lib` does exist. I then thought that maybe something was wrong with the fftw3.lib file, so I dumped out the symbols using `dumpbin.exe`. All the symbols that the linker says are missing are actually there, e.g. the corresponding dump block for `fftw_execute`

```
  Version      : 0
  Machine      : 8664 (x64)
  TimeDateStamp: 5DC30B59 Wed Nov  6 19:05:13 2019
  SizeOfData   : 00000017
  DLL name     : fftw3.dll
  Symbol name  : fftw_execute
  Type         : code
  Name type    : name
  Hint         : 60
  Name         : fftw_execute
```

So, if I understand correctly, the lib file is fine. On Unix systems, I can just tell the linker where to go by specifying the `-lfftw` flag, but apparently, that doesn't exist on MSVC. I am confused, because the linker flag `/LIBPATH:C:\Users\pavli\miniconda3\envs\tsne\Library\lib` is passed, but apparently it's not finding the fftw3.lib file? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: *"On Unix systems, I can just tell the linker where to go by specifying the -lfftw"* - that's not what that does; that tells the linked *what* to link. The "where to find stuff to link" (i.e. where to look for the "what") is a different linker option, and a similar scenario plays out with MS' toolchain. You have to provide *two* things: where to look for link libraries, and which libraries you want to use therein.

Comment: C compilers on Unix (at least, the one I know) use `-l` to name libs to link and `-L` to provide paths to search libs. This is similar for MSVC although the parameter for search path is `/LIBPATH` while libraries are given as input files. [.Lib Files as Linker Input](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/dot-lib-files-as-linker-input)

Comment: Yes, I should have been more precise, on Unix systems I add the library path using `-L` and tell which libraries to use with `-l`. Oh, thanks, specifying the full path of `fftw3.lib` did the trick. What, then, is the purpose of specifying `/LIBPATH` if I have to put in the full path anyways? Is there a way to do this without having to specify `/LIBPATH:C:\Users\pavli\miniconda3\envs\tsne\Library\lib\fftw3.lib` as a parameter?

Comment: You didn't list the fftw3.lib file on your command line. You gave the path, but you never said that you wanted fftw3.lib. The linker doesn't search every library in the path. Setting the LIBPATH means you can say "fftw3.lib" and the linker will look in all of the LIBPATHs for it. (Without LIBPATH, you'd have to give the full path to fftw3.lib.) It's like in C: You can add a directory to your INCLUDES path, but you still have to `#include` it. The compiler doesn't just include everything in the directory by default.

Comment: Thank you, that's very helpful. If you pack this into a short answer, I'll close the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per the comments, I did not specify `fftw3.lib` in the arguments of `link.exe`. `/LIBPATH` behaves like the `-L` flag on unix compilers and there is no equivalent for the `-l` flag. Instead, we have to pass either the full lib path or just the lib filename.